# Reference mongoose schema definition in swagger-jsdoc?

Tags: express, mongoose, swagger

I've built a express.js project with a mongoDB backend using mongoose.
Since I've created the mongoose models via mongoose schemas, I was wondering if it is possible to reference to the mongoose schema definition instead of re-typing all it's contents.

I'm currently using swagger-jsdoc.

Thanks and best regards

**[/EDIT]**
I understand, that [mongoose-to-swagger](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongoose-to-swagger) basically performs this task.
However, I have no clue how I can reference to such a generated swagger schema within my swagger-jsdoc code comments.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had the exact same issue and how i resolved it was i made a file called `swaggerSchemas` where i exported all the schemas like in the following example:

```
export default {
  user: m2s(User),
};
```

Where `User` is the mongoose model.
And finally inside your swagger jsdoc options you need something like the following:

```
const options = {
      definition: {
       ...
        components: {
          schemas: swaggerSchemas,
        },
       ...
      },
      ...
};
```

Comment: Cool, quite basic and obvious! Thanks, Luka!

Comment: And how do you use it in schema in code i mean in route comments.

Answer (score 0):

Adding to the current answer, you can reference the schema like so:

```
$ref: '#/components/schemas/user
```

This information is in the swagger documentation here
https://swagger.io/docs/specification/using-ref/